# Different rendering of character intersection with specified opacity

Tags: css, google-chrome, render, opacity

I have just noticed strange behavior of semi-transparent text with negative `letter-spacing` in Chrome. Basically, this CSS leads to darker intersections:

```
div {
  opacity: .5;
  letter-spacing: -.2em;
}
```

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Is there any CSS instruction to handle with this, so intersections will look the same in different browsers? Screenshot was made in Win Chrome 76.0.3809.100 (64-bit)

Fiddle → https://jsfiddle.net/yakunins/gcatnksh/

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like bug in Chrome — https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006140